# Displaying a specific key of an NSMutableArray in a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting data from the internet in a NSDictionary. The data I get is the following.

```
title
 => title
 state
 => state
 since
 => since
 list
 => list
```

I want now to display the title in my table cell. Previously I did it like this.

```
[projects setObject:[snapshot.value objectForKey:@"title"] forKey:projectItem];
```

But the problem now was, that I also needed the state, and not only the title. So I tried to add the whole `NSDictionary` to an `NSMutableDictionary`

Previously the table cell only printed out the title, now it makes a new entry for each entry in the Dictionary. But I also need to display the title and save the state into a new variable.

This is how I currently display the data

```
NSArray *tempKeys           = [projects allKeys];
NSString *tempIdentifier    = [tempKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text         = [todoLists objectForKey:[tempKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

which is wrong, since this will print out all the keys. What would be the way to display only the title for each entry and save the state into a variable?

Comment: I love the people who downvote but don't even edit the answer or provide a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to display are not the keys of the dictionary, but their values.
Try `NSArray *tempKeys = [projects allValues];`

Comment: And how would I then access the values? It looks like this now

(
    test,
    started,
    0,
    "-JAbFlvwYXI2R6j8Cc_-"
)

Comment: While Arrays are ordered, Dictionaries are not. I'd recommend you to use the keys to get whatever value you need. You can do that like this: ```[projects objectForKey:@"title"]```, or shortly, ```projects[@"title"]```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSArray *keysArray =[[NSArray alloc]initwithObjects:@"title",@"state",@"since",nil];

suppose your info array name is objectInfoArray...

for(int i=0; i< objectInfoArray.Count;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j< keysArray;j++)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@",[[objectInfoArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:j]]);

    }
}
```